# Buildozer не работает c Kivy MD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Столкнулся с проблемой, что мой код с kivy MD не хочет конвентироватся в APK, хотя не знаю в чём проблема
Код ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Buildozer.spec:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё вроде делал по инструкции (Устанавливал с помощью https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD-data/blob/master/install-kivy-buildozer-dependencies.sh), но что-то ничего не получается(

Comment: Может, я, конечно, не прав. Но судя по тексту, ему не нравится пробел в пути

Comment: Да и в принципе, я бы с кириллицей не рисковал

Comment: Хм,спасибо, Александр, дело и правда было в кириллице)